# tests failing cause a package was not installed, but the package is installed?

Tags: python, testing, package

I'm working on a repo that has about 236 tests, after running the tests, they all seem to be failing since there's a package that was not installed. I checked on the root folder with pip list, and the required package *is* installed. So i'm not understanding what's the problem. The package is something that was built here and I installed it in the root directory with the `.whl` extension.

Comment: Can you please show the error, your code?

Comment: So for every test, I have the following error:

`ImportError: No module named 'pwpcore'`

And in the root directory of the project I have the following packages installed:

```appdirs (1.4.3)
petl (1.1.1)
pip (9.0.1)
pwpcore (2.2.8)
zeep (2.4.0)
```

pwpcore is installed so i'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: Would be interesting to give more details, like the list of pip installed packages, and how `pwpcore` should be used (is there any documentation available, or a part of the source code, like the content of its `setup.py` or an `__init__.py` that would let know the content of `__all__` for instance). Maybe it just does not provide any pwpcore module, but you'll have to `import pwpcore.somemodule`. Impossible to tell without any more details.

Comment: Hey so I figured it out, turns out i'm I was in the wrong environment so the packages were not installed there!